# Determine if two resource id's point to same layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android setup that has a resource file that refers to a single layout from a choice of two.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
     <item name="another_resource_id" type="layout">@layout/some_layout</item>
</resources>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
     <item name="another_resource_id" type="layout">@layout/some_layout2</item>
</resources>
```

This produces the R.layout

```
public static final class layout {
    ...
    public static final int another_resource_id=0x7f030000;
    public static final int some_layout=0x7f030001;
    public static final int some_layout2=0x7f030002;
    ...
}
```

So the issue is that from the code I want to be able to tell which layout the **another_resource_id** resource identifier refers to.

Comment: maybe `Resources.getResourceName()` help

Comment: @Jiang YD This will only return some_layout or another_resource_id depending on the resId used.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my question:  Seems there is no straight forward way to tell the root view for a layout EXCEPT to dig down and get the original XML for the layout.  Comparing the two is how I am able to tell if they are the same view.  Kind of the long way around, but there it is.  The following code just compares the addition of the resouce id for the underlying elements.  Obviously you could put a lot more complex logic in.

```
 try {
       XmlResourceParser xrp = ctx.getResources().getLayout(id);
       int eventType;
       xrp.next();

       String resourceIds = "";
       do {
           eventType = xrp.nextToken();
           if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
               int attrs = xrp.getAttributeCount();
               if (attrs > 0) {
                   for (int i = 0; i < attrs; i++) {
                       if (xrp.getAttributeName(i).compareTo("id") == 0) {
                           resourceIds += xrp.getAttributeValue(i);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       } while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);

       returnVal = resourceIds.hashCode();

   } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            //            e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //          e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
            //        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            //      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```